# how to vertically align a div within padding top of relative parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align in the middle several lines of text next to an image which is also centred in its own div.

The parent div of both picture and text div is responsive.

The way I align the picture seems to prevent alignment of the text. I tried with tables and other solutions (also found in stack overflow), but nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.parent-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    border-top: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    margin-top: 1vw;
    margin-bottom: 1vw;
}

.image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 30%;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    background: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.text-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
    padding-top: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text-details {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: center;
}

.some-text {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.other-text {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.another-text {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-wrapper">
                
   <div class="image-wrapper">
      <div class="image" style="background-image: url('folder/picture.jpg');" alt="image">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="text-wrapper">
      <div class="text-details">
         <div class="some-text">some text</div>
         <div class="other-text">other text</div>
         <div class="another-text">another text</div>
      </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried css flexbox? You can apply it to parent element, and then align child elements however you want, without position: absolute or relative

Comment: You should be able to achieve that result using flex as mentioned by @mirza, you can see that in action here: https://jsbin.com/riligerivu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;
  height:50vh;
  background-color:blue;
}
.box-to-center{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box-to-center">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```